# Supply boolean to rpy2 kwargs

Tags: python, boolean, rpy2, keyword-argument

I am not sure how to convert between pythons' booleans and R - ones. Basically I have a function that I am trying to run:

```
seurat_object <- seuratLib.FindVariableGenes(
    seurat_object,
    **{
        'x.low.cutoff': 0.0125,
        'x.high.cutoff': 3,
        'y.cutoff': 0.5,
        'do.plot': False
    }
)
```

The final argument in the function - `'do.plot': False` - is the boolean one and just supplying the pythons' `False` is not working. I would expect to retrieve the `Rs'` `FALSE` from some `rpy2` singleton object, e.g. `rpy2.robjects.r.FALSE` but unfortunately I can not find anything like that in the newest `rpy2` version. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I figured it out. I needed to create a vector with one element `robjects.vectors.BoolVector([False])` for the `False` value:

```
seurat_object = seuratLib.FindVariableGenes(seurat_object, **{'x.low.cutoff': 0.0125, 
    'x.high.cutoff': 3, 'y.cutoff': 0.5, 'do.plot': robjects.vectors.BoolVector([False])})
```